# localhost refused to connect when trying to access jenkins on windows

Tags: jenkins

I installed jenkins on my windows PC and it was installed successfully. I put the installation on port 8085 and was able to access jenkins by visiting localhost:8085, then I shut down my PC. However, the next day when I opened my PC again it gave localhost refused to connect!

I did not give a user while installing and it was running locally.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Start Jenkins server again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess Jenkins was installed as windows service, so after restarting your PC Jenkins service on your machine was stopped.
For automatically starting your Jenkins service after failures, you should check properties of service --> recovery settings.